# Modify square and circle using Open layer 3

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, openlayers-3

I am new for Open layer and using open layer 3.I draw square on map using 4 coordinates. but now I want to edit that square by stretching any of one point but make sure it should not change shape of square(rectangle) to other shape.

Right now, I am using **[ol.interaction.Modify](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html)** but it's modify only for **Point**,**Linestring** and **Polygon**.

How would I extent this to support modification of circle and square(rectangle)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean by modifying square. You can modify a rectangle with the `modify.interaction` but you can not reshape it. I guess you mean reshape and not just modify. If this is your case , ol3 does not support it out of the box. But [here](http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.interaction.transform.html) there is an extension to do the reshape for every possible geometry (rectangle, polygon etc.) I am not sure whether it supports circles.

Comment: Thanks for Responce,

link which you gave in "here" is useful for me but can I see that code. I mean how I can use "ol.interaction.Transform" that i don't known.

Because In Open layer 3 API "ol.interaction.Transform" is not available.

Comment: You need to iclude the extension library . After all you need to do a bit of research as functinality you are looking for is not included out of the box. So go to this link https://github.com/Viglino/ol3-ext and see the project